# Data Abstraction and Encapsulation

Tags: java, constructor, interface, encapsulation, abstraction

I am trying to implement a small Program for doing basic Calculations, By using Data Abstraction and Encapsulation. 
But the Output for Each case is yielding Zero.
Can anyone find the Mistake where I am Wrong in implementing the Code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 interface Sum
 {
  int sum();
 }
interface Sub extends Sum
{
    int sub();
}
    interface Mul extends Sub
    {
        int mul();
    }
        interface Div extends Mul
        {
            int div();
        }
  class Algebra implements Sum,Mul,Sub,Div
  {
   private int number1,number2;
Algebra()
{
    number1=0;
    number2=0;
}
    Algebra(int number1,int number2)
    {
        this.number1=number1;
        this.number2=number2;
    }

        public int sum()
        {
            return number1+number2;
        }
        public int mul()
        {
            return number1*number2;
        }
        public int div()
        {
            return number1/number2;
        }
        public int sub()
        {
            return number1-number2;
        }
}
class Test
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int number1,number2;
    char choice;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    Algebra A=new Algebra();
    Div d;
    d=(Algebra)A;
    System.out.println("Enter the number 1 : ");
    number1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the numbre 2 : ");
    number2=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter choice : 1.)Sum 2.)Mul 3.)Div 4.)Sub ");
    choice=input.next().charAt(0);
    d=new Algebra(number1,number2);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':
            System.out.println("Sum is : "+d.sum());
            break;
            case '2':
            System.out.println("Mul is : "+d.mul());
            break;
            case '3':
            System.out.println("Div is : "+d.div());
            break;
            case '4':
            System.out.println("Sub us : "+d.sub());
            break;
        }
}
}
```

Output Is zero for Each case.

Comment: format your code property

Comment: Why do your operators inherit from one another? Can't you just have an `Operator` interface and an implementation for Mul/Sub/Div etc?

Comment: You are creating 2 Algebra objects `Algebra A=new Algebra(); d=(Algebra)A;` and `new Algebra(number1,number2);` you are passing your arguments to 1 object and then use the other to call the calculation methods. Thats like entering data on one calculator and then going to another calculator and pressing the equal sign. It won't work obviously.

Comment: A quick fix to your issue `d = new Algebra(number1,number2);` Overall you're lacking of basic understanding of software design.

Comment: Got Your Point @OHGODSPIDERS thanks. I am using private variables that are not the property of the interfaces.

Comment: @DenIsahac Practice Makes the Men Perfect. BTW Thanks for your Help with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Formatted the Code on receiving valuable suggestions from Peers.
Final code is as Follow.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*Data Abstraction Using interface */
interface Operation
{
int sum();
int mul();
int sub();
int div();
}

/* Or Using Abstract Class

abstract class Operation
{
    abstract int sum();
    abstract int mul();
    abstract int sub();
    abstract int div();
}
class Algebra extends Operation  (Inheritance)
{
    code..
}
*/

class Algebra implements Operation 
{
private int number1,number2;
Algebra()
{
    number1=0;
    number2=0;
}
    Algebra(int number1,int number2)
    {
        this.number1=number1;
        this.number2=number2;
    }

    /* Encapsulation of the Data Memebers and Functions*/
        public int sum()
        {
            return number1+number2;
        }
        public int mul()
        {
            return number1*number2;
        }
        public int div()
        {
            return number1/number2;
        }
        public int sub()
        {
            return number1-number2;
        }
}
class Test 
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int number1,number2;
    char choice;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    Algebra A=new Algebra(); //Dynamic Object of Sub Class
    Operation Op; //Static Object
    Op=(Algebra)A; //Type Casting of the Static Object of interface or abstract class
    System.out.println("Enter the number 1 : ");
    number1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the numbre 2 : ");
    number2=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter choice : 1.)Sum 2.)Mul 3.)Div 4.)Sub ");
    choice=input.next().charAt(0);
    Op=new Algebra(number1,number2);


        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':
            System.out.println("Sum is : "+Op.sum());
            break;
            case '2':
            System.out.println("Mul is : "+Op.mul());
            break;
            case '3':
            System.out.println("Div is : "+Op.div());
            break;
            case '4':
            System.out.println("Sub us : "+Op.sub());
            break;
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix your problem you might want to replace

```
new Algebra(number1,number2);
```

with

```
d = new Algebra(number1,number2);
```

in your code your object d is the default one with number1 and number2 set to zero.

You might also want to format your code and think about your interfaces hierarchy which does not seem really useful

Comment: I just Started with interface and inheritance , I am not pro at this. I will be good at this soon. Thanks for the Fix